# jsfiddle code working but when in demo page is not

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

I am testing [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/mhJXt/242/) written by [@Ilan Biala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1536154/ilan-biala)

It adds a submenu in a menu using **jquery 1.9.0**, **onDomReady** and **Normalized css** as you can see on the jsfiddle.
For instance the html is:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" >Sec1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" >Sec2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="current">Sec3</a></li>
        <li><a href="contacto.html" >Sec4</a></li>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="documents" data-icon="&#xe000">Documents</a></li>
            <br>
            <li><a href="#" class="messages" data-icon="&#xe001">Messages</a></li>
            <br>
            <li><a href="#" class="signout" data-icon="&#xe002">Sign Out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

the result is:

[image]

But there is an issue, I am adding the code to a [server I have access](http://eurekavi.com/example.html), and Added the lines:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css"  />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>
```

to emulate those in jsfiddle. The html is:

```
 <!doctype html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css"  />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" >Sec1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" >Sec2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="current">Sec3</a></li>
        <li><a href="contacto.html" >Sec4</a></li>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="documents" data-icon="&#xe000">Documents</a></li>
            <br>
            <li><a href="#" class="messages" data-icon="&#xe001">Messages</a></li>
            <br>
            <li><a href="#" class="signout" data-icon="&#xe002">Sign Out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

So, as you can see the submenu is not working, what could be causing the glitch?

I am suspecting different issues:

1. Maybe the **onDomReady** property that wraps the code so it will run in onDomReady window event, if so How do I indicate that on code :

   $(document).ready(function() {
     //ADD ALL THE JS CODE IN menu.js
   });
2. The Normalized css, but that is suposed to make a reset....
3. Theres is an issue in the jquery 1.9.0, maybe the order the using js are placed...

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the same fiddle here modified to work with what you want: [**JS Fiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/OMS_/mhJXt/258/)

Its the exact same fiddle that you posted, just **onDomReady** set to "**no wrap (head)**" and JavaScript code wrapped in `ready` function. This makes it work with the HTML you have posted.

```
// jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
jQuery(function($) {
 ....
 // your code
});
```

So, as an answer, when you have jQuery loaded in `head` tag of your `html` document, you need to use `.ready()` API of jQuery and wrap all your code for any DOM manipulation in the `ready` `function`

Answer (score 2):

yes you are right;

onDomReadycode is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//your code
})
```

as if you change the event in jsfiddle to body wrap it would not work.

Comment: So if I understand I should put 
`<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
// the menu.js
})
</script>`   in the html, or in the menu.js I do 

`$(document).ready(function(){
// the menu.js functions
})`  
which option?

Comment: open menu.js and write at top of file at start $(document).ready(function(){ and at the end of file put });